# How to do simple VR gesture/movement recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, gesture, gesture-recognition

For my university project I am making a program to help test children's motor skills. Its basic ball catching/throwing tests, but there are certain steps involved, eg, for an underarm throw the movement goes as follows:

- dominant hand swings down and back reaching behind the leg
- steps forward with the foot opposite the throwing hand
- ball is tossed forward hitting the wall without a bounce
- hand follows through after ball release to chest level

For these detections I am initially thinking of buffering a list of points before each 'step' of positions and then checking each one over for that step to be performed.
Is there any elegant way of doing this? Any mathematical way that isn't a neural network?

My proposed method feels a bit crude, so i'd love input from anyone else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive got - 2 on this questions so obviously i shouldn't be asking such a ridiculous question on here. Its fine. Ill figure it out.